# How to get PdfpTable Width working?

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

So I've been trying to find out how to get table width working with no success for a particular case.

I have a table with 2 columns. In the second column I add one cell that includes a table with one column. In this cell, I add a table with one column and then add a cell with text and then another PdfPTable with two columns.

Now this last PdfPTable I seam to be unable to manipulate. SetTotalWidth and WidthPercentage does nothing, nothing changes at all. I simply just want to make this table less wide.

Am I doing something wrong or does itextcharp have bugs?

Answer (score 0):

4 nested tables? This is one that really, really needs some sample code so we can all get on the same page. Below is something that hopefully abstracts away whatever you are doing to the bare essentials. Does it look right? This isn't an answer but instead a starting point so we have something to work with.

I set the widths on the outermost and innermost tables and its working for me just fine. The outer table is getting blown out because of the inner tables but that's to be expected.

```
        string sampleFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Sample.pdf");
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sampleFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
            {
                using (PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                {
                    doc.Open();

                    PdfPTable t1 = new PdfPTable(2);
                    PdfPTable t2 = new PdfPTable(1);
                    PdfPTable t3 = new PdfPTable(1);
                    PdfPTable t4 = new PdfPTable(2);

                    t1.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 10f, 40f });
                    t4.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 40f, 10f });

                    t4.AddCell("t4a");
                    t4.AddCell("t4b");
                    t3.AddCell(t4);
                    t2.AddCell(t3);
                    t1.AddCell("t1a");
                    t1.AddCell(t2);

                    doc.Add(t1);

                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nearly, the latest table I first put into a cell and then add it. And I do not get the table to change it's width..

Comment: First I add a cell with usually a lot of text into t3, then comes the table t4 table which I for some reason first add to a cell, which I've now changed to directly add into t4 after the text. That however did not make itextsharp apply the width commands.

Comment: It would really help if you posted some sample code, keep it as simple as possible because nesting anything a bunch of times can add lots of complexity.